# What governs the loading of TS in a browser debugger?

Tags: javascript, typescript, source-maps

What governs the loading of TS in a browser debugger?

Broadly the answer is "the .map file(s)" and the most common issue is broken paths due to build issues. However I don't think that's the problem here since the map file looks like this

```
{
  "version": 3,
  "file": "CoreWidgets.js",
  "sourceRoot": "",
  "sources": [ "CoreWidgets.ts" ],
  "names": [],
  "mappings": "AAAA,0DAA0D;AAC1D,4DAA4D;AAC5D,wDAAwD;...,QAuThB"
}
```

and I'm  deploying the .js, .ts and .js.map files to the same folder.

Some important background:

- Bundling is not in play.
- One file works fine but others don't.
- All files are generated by the TypeScript 2.4 compiler from the VS2017 IDE
- All .js files as shown in the browser debugger contain exactly one mapping reference comment as the last line in the file.
- All .js.map files have the same form as the excerpt above (all three files in same folder).
- The problem seems to be restricted to Edge, so I flushed the browser cache and restarted the browser, to no avail. Everything is hunky dory in Chrome, apart from the hideous user interface and my distaste for Google at large.

### update

The same version of Edge on another computer does not experience the problem. Since I have already tried clearing the file cache I will now try clearing everything but cookies and browser history.

Comment: The problem is that server must respond by 200 OK to request with url built using combination of current **base path** in HTML head, **sourceRoot** property from map file and **file name**. If path is built wrong and your server to request response with non 200 status (usualy 404) browser canot access original source. Some browsers report this issue to console (F12).

Comment: There are known issue in VS 2017, that Visual Studio in some case built files differently while Compiling on save than Building project. See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/57099/typescript-generated-source-maps-have-invalid-path.html?childToView=67117

Comment: @Misaz - thank you for trying to help. I followed your link but sadly that is a different problem.

Comment: See browser console at network tab what request does browser do? Alternatively see server log what requests was received and was response was sent.